# VSCode: How to delay a task command's execution after shell creation

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VSCode's launch.json, I've defined a `preLaunchTask` called `preRun`. The task (in tasks.json) looks like this:

from tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "preRun",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "openocd -f board/esp32-wrover-kit-3.3v.cfg"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is the shell that's being created within which the command is executed needs some time to configure itself before the command is executed. How can I delay the command's execution for a couple of seconds?